# Log4j2 custom fields Socket appender

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm currently sending information from my Java application to ELK using Log4j2 and socketAppender. I'd like to know if it's possible to add extra information to this message sent to ELK with things like, application name, original request, and stuff like that:

My configuration right now looks like this:

```
Configuration:
  name: Remote

  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: Console
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{10}:%L - %m%n"
    Socket:
      name: Elk
      port: 7000
      host: elk
      reconnectionDelayMillis: 10000
      SerializedLayout: []
```

Any clue or documentation about how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add key-value pairs to the ThreadContext. These will be included in the LogEvent. SerializedLayout will also include this so you should be able to receive it on the other end of the socket.